# Server and Client run on customer machine, should I use HTTPS, and how?

Tags: https, server, localhost

I am developing a program that consists of a .NET CORE based server and a JS client that runs in the web browser. When a customer runs the program it starts the server (on the customer machine) and pops up a web page pointed to localhost.

My understanding of HTTPS leads me to believe that to use it, the server (which means the customer machine) would need access to the private key. To me that means each customer should have their own private key, but the matching public key is supposed to be verified by a certificate authority so the browser will trust the site.

I want the experience for the customer to be as seamless as possible, so if they have to manually add a security exception to the browser that is no good.

My Question is, is it feasible to use HTTPS in this case and if so, how? Is it even necessary? Will web browsers stop allowing HTTP in the next 10-20 years? (Edit: It looks like yes, but maybe not for 127.0.0.1?) Since everything is local host does HTTPS provide any security benefit?

*Edit:* I found a good let's encrypt article [here](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/certificates-for-localhost/) that mentions Web Sockets, so I want to point out that this program uses those as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I got the tumbleweed badge for this question. I was hoping there might be a way to generate SSL keys on the fly or something, but it looks like there isn't so http is the way to go here. Http is going to go away long term, but it looks like it may continue to be supported for localhost. If not, when the features I need start getting removed from newer versions of web browsers I will switch to electron if I haven't already so I can control the browser version customers use, and just use the latest version that still supports everything.